# Hi I am trying to push the run time values that i am getting from the odata services through ajax calls to the highcharts

Tags: highcharts, odata

Following is the code that I have developed:

```
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

---

```
  $(function(){

    var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line'
      },

      xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        labels: {
          y: 20,
          rotation: -45,
          align: 'right'
        }
      },
      series: []
    };

    var oDataUrlEntity = serviceUrl;

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: oDataUrlEntity,
      username: "xxxx",
      password: "xxxx",
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      timeout: 5000,
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        debugger;
        data_poRequest = {
          rootNode: []
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
          var obj = data.d.results[i];
          data_poRequest.rootNode.push({
            key1: obj.fieldName1,
            key2: obj.fieldName2

          });
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data_poRequest.rootNode.length; i++) {
          debugger;
          options.xAxis.categories.push(data_poRequest.rootNode[i]['fieldName']);
          series = {
            data: []
          };
          series.data.push(data_poRequest.rootNode[0]);
          options.series.push(series);
          //                   
        }
        debugger;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      }
    });    
  });
```

The problem is now on the `highcharts` I am getting only one value out of the `24 values` in the `cateogies` array.Also only the `legend` is coming with 24 series.

Also,in the debugger i can see values inside `options.xAxis.categories` & also inside `series.data`,But they are not getting reflected on the Highcharts.

Could anyone help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's impossible to help you until you show us the `data` that's being returned by the ajax call.

Comment: data.d.results[0]=
Object {__metadata: Object, PoRelInfo: Object, CreatedBy: "", CreatedOn: "/Date(1403654400000)/", Currency: "INR"…}
CreatedBy: ""
CreatedOn: "/Date(1403654400000)/"
DocType: "STPO"
PoNumber: "5001000030"

Comment: I have 24 records in the data,and multiple keys out of which i want value against PoNumber to be y axis & value against DocType to be categories in xAxis.

Comment: structure is: data_poRequest:[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object],[object object] and every object has a structure above

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating every time new series. Won't you have instead one series?

So change:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data_poRequest.rootNode.length; i++) {
      debugger;
      options.xAxis.categories.push(data_poRequest.rootNode[i]['fieldName']);
      series = {
        data: []
      };
      series.data.push(data_poRequest.rootNode[0]);
      options.series.push(series);
      //                   
    }
```

To:

```
    series = {
      data: []
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < data_poRequest.rootNode.length; i++) {
      options.xAxis.categories.push(data_poRequest.rootNode[i]['fieldName']);
      series.data.push(data_poRequest.rootNode[0]);
    }
    options.series.push(series);
```